# File always save with underscore

Tags: 7, forms, files

I have a custom form where admin users upload a CSV file. Everything is working fine, but the file is saved with an underscore. For example, I upload **callLog4127_Lorem_20170701.csv** but the file is saved as **callLog4127_Lorem_20170701_1.csv**.

I checked the database, but I don't find any reference to callLog4127_Lorem_20170701. I also deleted the temp folder, and ran cron, but I am still getting the same problem.

It happens just with this file; when I upload another file it's working correctly, which means the filename is not changed.

This is my form validation handler. Is there anything wrong with it that could cause the behavior I am seeing?

```
function upload_rtap_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $file = file_save_upload('calllogrtap_file', array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('csv'), // Validate extensions.
    'public://mrtap/', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE
  ));

  if ($file) {
    $file = file_move($file, 'public://mrtap/', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    $file->status = 1;
    file_save($file);
    $form_state['storage']['filename'] = $file->uri;
  }
}
```

If I print the content of `$file` with `print_r($file)`, after `file_save_upload()`, I get the following.

```
stdClass Object(
  [uid] => 1
  [status] => 0
  [filename] => callLog4127_GentleDental_20170701.csv
  [uri] => temporary://callLog4127_GentleDental_20170701_4.csv
  [filemime] => text/csv
  [filesize] => 48429
  [source] => calllogrtap_file
  [destination] => temporary://callLog4127_GentleDental_20170701_4.csv
  [timestamp] => 1501309335
  [fid] => 235
 )
```

Comment: As side note, that code is moving the file twice: once with `file_save_upload()`, and once with `file_move()`.

Comment: What you are showing is the form validation handler, but what does the form submission handler do?

Comment: In submit just insert data in custom table

Answer (score 0):

The main error is that you aren't passing the last two arguments of  [`file_save_upload()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7.x) to that function, since you are putting them in the array you pass as second argument. The code you are using is the following one; see the comments I added.

```
  $file = file_save_upload('calllogrtap_file', array(
    // First line of the array
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('csv'),
    'public://mrtap/', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE
    // Last line of the array
  ));
```

As you aren't passing the last two arguments to `file_save_upload()`, the function is using the default values for those parameters, which are:

- `$destination = FALSE`
- `$replace = FILE_EXISTS_RENAME`

The first values is making Drupal save the uploaded file in temporary://; the second value is telling Drupal to rename the file if there is already a file with that name.

The function call should be the following one.

```
  $file = file_save_upload('calllogrtap_file', array('file_validate_extensions' => array('csv')), 'public://mrtap/', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

If you change the code in this way, then the following code line is not necessary, since the uploaded file is already moved in public://mrtap/ from the call to `file_save_upload()`.

```
$file = file_move($file, 'public://mrtap/', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

If *filename* is the ID of the form element for uploading the file, the following code probably needs to be changed.

```
$form_state['storage']['filename'] = $file->uri;
```

Probably, the correct line is the following one.

```
$form_state['values']['filename'] = $file;
```

I would also keep the code to validate the user input in `upload_rtap_validate()`, and the code saving the file as managed file in `upload_rtap_submit()`.
For example, see the code used from the form handlers for [`system_theme_settings()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/function/system_theme_settings/7.x), [`system_theme_settings_validate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/function/system_theme_settings_validate/7.x) and [`system_theme_settings_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/function/system_theme_settings_submit/7.x). (I replaced the comments with mine.)

```
  // system_theme_settings_validate()
  $file = file_save_upload('logo_upload', $validators);
  if (isset($file)) {
    // The user upload the logo file.
    if ($file) {
      // The uploaded file passed the validation in $validators.
      $form_state['values']['logo_upload'] = $file;
    }
    else {
      // The file upload failed.
      form_set_error('logo_upload', t('The logo could not be uploaded.'));
    }
  }
```

```
  // system_theme_settings_submit()
  // If the user uploaded a new logo, save it to a permanent location.
  if (!empty($values['logo_upload'])) {
    $file = $values['logo_upload'];
    unset($values['logo_upload']);
    $filename = file_unmanaged_copy($file->uri);
    $values['default_logo'] = 0;
    $values['logo_path'] = $filename;
    $values['toggle_logo'] = 1;
  }
```

In your case, you could use [`file_copy()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_copy/7.x) instead of [`file_unmanaged_copy()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_copy/7.x), or [`file_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save/7.x) as your code is doing.

Comment: Basically this, and also one of my main issues with the core file field. But since this is in custom code, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE is the way to go.